# WebBrowser.Navigate overload doesn't add cookies

Tags: c#, cookies, browser

I'm experimenting with C#, and right now I'm trying to get a web page that needs cookies. Since I had no success doing it, I wrote this little PHP script ( directly from php.net):

```
<?php   
    foreach (getallheaders() as $name => $value) {
        echo "$name: $value\n";
    }
?>
```

but, when i run:

```
this.WBro.Navigate("http://localhost/cookie.php", null,null,"Cookie: foo=bar");
```

the foo cookie isn't there, and all I got is a page displaying the "usual" headers ( except the cookie one). Does somebody has any idea of why this happens?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it work if you add an Environment.NewLine after the header?

Comment: if this is what you mean : this.WBro.Navigate("http://localhost/cookie.php", null, null, "Cookie: sid=1234" + System.Environment.NewLine); no, it doesn't work

Comment: Does it work with other, custom headers? Like X-Cookie: whatever ?

Comment: Yes, it works for every other header i set, except for Cookie. Maybe it's a sort of "protection"? I haven't found anything about it even googling...

Comment: Maybe the problem is that (afaik) Cookie header must be the last one, but when I set a header with the navigate method, it's always placed as the first one...

Comment: Then I guess cookies are disabled. Adjust Internet explorer settings, add localhost to the trusted sites, something like that.

Comment: Even if I: 1) set privacy option to "Accept all cookies" and 2) added http://localhost to trusted sites, nothing changed. Sick method...

Comment: I found your answer: you can't do this, try pinvoke InternetSetCookie. http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.inetsdk.programming.webbrowser_ctl/browse_frm/thread/e98f8997be78d413

Comment: Seeing that nothing has changed since 2001 isn't very reassuring .. but well, thanks for thte information :)

Comment: Using `Environemnt.NewLine` is *not* good defensive coding here. HTTP headers call for a *very specific* termination, mainly: CRLF or "\r\n". `Environment.NewLine` is not guaranteed to always return "\r\n", depending upon environment. (Even though am not sure if Mono [on Linux] can even host a WebBrowser control...)

Answer (score 2):

For future reference: there's no way to set cookies with WebBrowser.Navigate. Just use

```
[DllImport("wininet.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool InternetSetCookie(string lpszUrl, string lpszCookieName, string lpszCookieData);
InternetSetCookie("http://localhost", "foo", "bar");
```

Comment: That's probably wrong usage. You should call InternetSetCookie("http://localhost", null, "foo=bar");